# RecyclerView adapter buffer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello I'm using [RecyclerViewPager](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager) for my calendar. One item of the `RecyclerViewPager` is `match_parent * match_parent` so `onCreateViewHolder` is called just once, and when I slide left or right then `onCreateViewHolder` is called. Since the view is a little big complex, with SQL queries, is there a way to prepare view on the left and on the right?

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you do a couple (or maybe all) of the SQL queries and other time consuming tasks before rendering the UI. That way when the user slides the UI it would provide them with a more smooth and consistent experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load your data before you need it using an AsyncTask, save the data you need right before presentation in your recyclerview. You basically want to warm up the cache to be ready to immediately serve your data when required.

Comment: Yes, but creating view itself without getting data is also time consuming, but I suppose I should optimize the logic

Comment: The idea is that you would retrieve the data before the point of time that View creation would occur. This way, when you either inflate/construct a new View or recycle a view from the pool, the execution of the method onBindViewHolder will be faster.